# react - children component not showing

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to insert a child component inside another child component, but my code is not working. Following codes are the structure i'm trying to build.

```
const AddProductPage= () => {
    return (
        <PageTemplate>
            <ProductTemplate>
                <AddProduct />
            </ProductTemplate>
        </PageTemplate>
    );
};
```

```
const PageTemplate= ({children}) => {
    return (
        <div className={cx('pagetemplate')}>
            <HeaderContainer />
            <main>
                {children}
            </main>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
};
```

```
class ProductTemplate extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={cx('product-template')}>
                ...
                <div className={cx('display')}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```
class AddProduct extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={cx('addproduct')}>
                addproduct
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I'm trying to insert AddProduct component in ProductTemplate component as a child, which is inserted in PageTemplate component as a child. AddProductPage, however, is not showing AddProduct component. I'd be grateful if anyone can help.

Comment: Your code is seems to be fine. Have you imported the `AddProduct`?

Comment: yeap. i imported AddProduct, but not showing. I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: check out console for any error or warning.

Answer (score 1):

I've run your code. May be you'r missing default export statements.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import AddProductPage from './AddProductPage';
ReactDOM.render(<AddProductPage />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

AddProductPage.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PageTemplate from './PageTemplate';
import ProductTemplate from './ProductTemplate';
import AddProduct from './AddProduct';

const AddProductPage= () => {
return (
    <PageTemplate>
        <ProductTemplate>
            <AddProduct />
        </ProductTemplate>
    </PageTemplate>
);
};

export default AddProduct;
```

PageTemplate.js

```
import React from 'react';

const PageTemplate= ({children}) => {
return (
    <div>
        <main>
            {children}
        </main>
    </div>
);
};

export default PageTemplate;
```

ProductTemplate.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

class ProductTemplate extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
};

export default ProductTemplate;
```

AddProduct.js

```
import  React, {Component} from 'react';

class AddProduct extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            addproduct
        </div>
    );
};
};

export default AddProduct;
```

Output is this :
`addproduct`

Answer (score 0):

Here`s a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c8eqfzrL/) of your code

Works Fine!. I have removed cx API. I suppose the problem might be with className resolution. Check in the dom hierarchy weather the Children DOM Node exists and they have received their respective classnames.

```
const PageTemplate= ({children}) => {
return (
    <div className={'pagetemplate'}>
        <HeaderContainer />
        <main>
            {children}
        </main>
        <Footer />
    </div>
 );
};
```

Comment: just finished checking the dom hierarchy as you suggested, but everything seems to be fine. it's really frustrating.. lol. guess i'm gonna keep looking. thx for your suggestion!